# How to append text or symbol to tooltip of chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Want to add % sign to tooltip of chart.js How to do ?

```
  var chart = new chart(ctx,{
   type:'bar',
   data : data
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
options : {
         tooltips: {
                  enabled: true,
                  mode: 'single',
                  callbacks: {
                           label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                                return  tooltipItems.yLabel + " %";
                           }
                  }
         }
```

Comment: I used this same technique to modify the values of my labels. Very helpful!

Comment: Trying to do this on a PIE chart with no luck. I presume "yLabel" would just be "label" for a pie ... not working. Thoughts?

Comment: Easiest and fastest

Comment: @whakawaehere better late than never. I did this:

const value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index]

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue 3+

```
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    yAlign: 'bottom',
    callbacks: {
      label(tooltipItems: any) {
        return `${tooltipItems.formattedValue} %`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works also for Pie Charts:

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'single',
    callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
            var i = tooltipItems.index;
            return data.labels[i] + ": " + data.datasets[0].data[i] + " %";
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is for Chartjs Version - 3.9.1

```
 tooltip: { 
    callbacks: {
     label: function (context) {
        return context.label + ': ' + context.formattedValue + '%';
     }
   }
 }
```

With this you can attach suffix or prefix to label value in tooltip.